# Batch script to ping remote computer every 5 seconds?

Tags: loops, batch-file, ping, repeat

I'm trying to create a script that pings my remote computer like every 5 or 10 seconds to see if it is back online after rebooting.

I have this code that seems to work but spams like crazy, and I only need it to check every 5 seconds or so.

A bonus to it would be if it stops the loop once it gets a successful connection.

```
@echo off
:loop
echo Checking connection...

ping -n 1 xx.xxx.xxx.xx >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  cls
  echo Computer is offline
  goto loop>nul

)

cls
echo Computer is online
  goto loop>nul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
:loop    
    ping -n 1 -w 500 -4 xx.xx.xx.xx 2>nul|find "TTL=" >nul||(echo offline & ping -w 1000 -n 6 localhost >nul & goto loop)
    echo online
```

Comment: Just what I need!
I just added a "pause >nul" at the end so it does not close when it get a response.

Answer (score 1):

Below would be the fine solution for your issue, i guess. try this script and let me know if tat works.

```
#!/bin/ksh
pingSuccess=0
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
        ping -c 1 $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && pingSuccess=1
        [ ${pingSuccess} -eq 1 ] && echo "got the successful ping. " && break
        echo "ping failed. sleeping for 5 secs" && sleep 5
done
echo "exitting.."; exit 0
```

Comment: hello.were do I insert the IP/computer name I want o ping?

Answer (score 0):

Did not test, but this should work:

```
@echo off
SET IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SET TIMEOUT=5000
:loop
echo Checking connection...

ping -n 1 %IP% >nul
if errorlevel not 0 (
  cls
  echo Computer at %IP% is offline, waiting %TIMEOUT%ms before retrying
  ping -n 1 1.0.0.1 -w %TIMEOUT% >nul
  goto loop>nul

)
echo Computer at %IP% is online
```

you can change

```
SET IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

to:

```
SET IP=%1
```

and give the IP address as argument to the batch file.

Also, make sure IP 1.0.0.1 is not reachable, it is used to create the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:pingagain
set /a inc+=5
set "ip=xx.xx.xx.xx"
Call :IsPingable %ip% && (
Echo %ip% is online
) || (
Echo %ip% is not online yet. 
ping  127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 5000>nul
goto :pingagain)
exit /b   

:IsPingable <comp>
ping -n 1 -w 3000 -4 -l 8 "%~1" | Find "TTL=">nul  
exit /b
```